# C: Temp file deleted immediately after opening

Tags: c, linux, unix, temp

I'm trying to make a temp file, to which I want write a bunch of stuff, and then print out upon receiving a signal. However, after some diagnostics with `lsof` it looks like the temp file is deleted immediately after opening it. Take the following snippet:

```
FILE *tmp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if ((tmp = tmpfile()) == NULL)
        err_sys("tmpfile error");

    sleep(60);
```

Now if I go do a `ps aux`, get the pid of my process, and then do a `lsof -p <pid>`, I see the following:

```
10.06   1159 daniel    3u   REG    0,1     0 10696049115128289 /tmp/tmpfCrM7Jn (deleted)
```

This is a bit of a head-scratcher for me. Considering that it's really only a single built in function call, which is not causing an error when being called, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: From the man page: *"The created file is
     unlinked before tmpfile() returns, causing the file to be automatically
     deleted when the last reference to it is closed."*

Comment: And "*last reference to it is closed*" when `fclose(tmp);` is called.

Comment: I should still be able to read and write to it though. Unlinking just means the path pointing to the inode is removed, the current file handle `FILE *tmp` should still be valid until, as @alk said, I either call `fclose` or the program exits.

Comment: Saying that I do see now why `lsof` says it is deleted, because the file path that pointed to it is gone, but the file handle is still open (hence why it shows up in `lsof` in the first place).

Comment: If you can't read or write to it, then you need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the code that writes and reads.

Comment: @user3386109: Why not make your first comment an answer?

Comment: I know the rules yeah, just seems I misdiagnosed where the problem was. Since realiding that this wasn't the problem, I've since fixed my code (signalling problem elsewhere), temp file and all. Make your first comment an answer and I'll mark it as correct, perhaps including the little clarification in my response about "Unlinking means the path pointing to the inode is removed, the current file handle FILE *tmp should still be valid"

Comment: Ok, I converted it to an answer.

Comment: @DanielPorteous Oops, we were editing at the same time. Please try again, and I'll approve.

Comment: @user3386109 I was doing pretty much the same thing as you haha, it's fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page:

> The created file is unlinked before tmpfile() returns, causing the
>   file to be automatically deleted when the last reference to it is
>   closed.

The output from `lsof` simply indicates that the path pointing to the inode was removed. However, the current file handle `FILE *tmp` should still be valid, until the file is closed, or the program exits.